# Element not found by id in DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am updating cells of dataTable very frequently using `id` as selector as each table cell that has to be updated already has unqiue `id` assigned. Below is the code

```
agentStatSocket.onmessage = function(e){
        
    data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    //console.log(data);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      try {
        var inboundTd = data[i]['id'] + '-inbound';
        var outboundTd = data[i]['id'] + '-outbound';

        if (data[i]['inboundCalls'] != 0) {
           document.getElementById(inboundTd).innerHTML = data[i]['inboundCalls'];
          }

        if (data[i]['outboundCalls'] != 0) { 
           document.getElementById(outboundTd).innerHTML = data[i]['outboundCalls'];
          }  

       } catch (error) {
           console.log(data[i]); 
       } 
   }
};
```

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` but that id is available in the dom.

I tried to catch error so that at least my loop shouldn't stop and i can get all that data using `console.log(data[i)` which is not present in the table. To my surprise there were at least 10 objects printed in console. This cannot happen because i can see the previous data is present in table. When i commented out the `DataTable()` function and reloaded the page i didn't see any error.

**Can you please tell me how to update table cells in DataTable as i need Search , Sort and Pagination functionality of DataTable ?**

Comment: Hard to tell what help you are expecting with the provided snippet.. all we can tell you is the same the console tells you: most likely there simply is no element with the provided `id` or that the set `id` is invalid. For the rest, check [the manual](https://datatables.net/manual/index).

Comment: @Lain Can you please tell me what code do you need? I do understand that this code tells that table cells are updated every time message is received but i was unsure what else should i provide.

Comment: _What code do you need_? Enough to recreate the problem: a [mre]. (You may even find that while doing this, you solve your own problem.)

Comment: Also, bear in mind that adding data to a cell in an HTML table is not the same as adding that data to the underlying DataTables object. DataTables will not know about such data, unless you use the DataTables API to add it (there are various ways to do this) - and then [redraw](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) the table.